# HtmlList: Select options in a select with padding

Tags: padding, html-select, coded-ui-tests

I am using a the property `SelectedItemsAsString` from a `HtmlList` object to select multiple items in a select-Tag.

```
myHtmlList.SelectedItemsAsString = new string[] {"a"};
```

This works as expected in a demo, but not in my productive website, because there my select-Tag has a left padding.

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="padding-left: 12px; width: 400px;">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

This results in a mouse click to far to the left of the actual option and therefor no option is selected.
Any ideas how I can make this work without removing the padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Seems like a CodedUI bug to me. Instead of clicking the list item control, it clicks on top left corner of selected item row.

As an alternative we can click and select items ourselves.

```
var selectedItems = new string[] { "a", "c" };

// Clear any existing selections
myHtmlList.SelectedIndices = new int[] { };

// Select items
myHtmlList.GetChildren().Cast<HtmlListItem>().ToList().ForEach(f =>
{
    Keyboard.PressModifierKeys(ModifierKeys.Control);
    if (selectedItems.Contains(f.DisplayText))
    {
        Mouse.Click(f);
    }
    Keyboard.ReleaseModifierKeys(ModifierKeys.Control);
});
```

Above code will find all children of HtmlList, cast them to HtmlListItem. For selection it will start by pressing "CTRL" key, and then for each list item if the display text matches with the selected item list, it will click on the list item. At the end it will release the "CTRL" key.

If there are lots of HtmlList items in your application, then i would suggest converting this to an extension method to HtmlList.

Something like this.

```
public static void SelectItems(this HtmlList htmlList, string[] selectedItems)
```